# Nested forms in Wicket: form "breaks"

Tags: java, html, forms, wicket

According to this wiki entry:

[Nested Forms](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Nested+Forms)

Wicket should support nested Forms.
However, when I try to use them, everything breaks.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
<form wicket:id="outer">
    <!-- some fields... -->

    <form wicket:id="inner">
        <!-- some fields... -->
    </form>

    <!-- some other fields... -->
</form>
```

It seems alright, but in the resulting HTML output the opening tag of the inner form:

```
<form wicket:id="inner">
```

is just missing. Completely gone!

This obviously means that the inner Form's closing `</form>` tag is now interpreted as the closing tag of the outer Form, and the last `</form>` closing tag doesn't have a corresponding opening tag anymore. Long story short: resulting HTML is incorrect and it breaks the whole page.

How do I prevent the inner Form's opening `<form ...>` tag from disappearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<form>` tag of the inner form is transformed to `<div>`. Same should be the case for its closing tag.

Nesting `<form>` inside another `<form>` is invalid according to HTML specifications!

Check whether your markup is valid before passing it to Wicket. You must have only one issue - the nested `<form>`s. Fix everything else!

Comment: That's my problem: the closing tag is NOT transformed into a div. It remains a </form>. That's what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Please re-read my answer. If it doesn't help then please create a demo application and attach it to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET